# Pass data from javascript to flask

Tags: javascript

I would like to pass some data to a python code with javascript. I used the onclick function of a button configuring it like this:

```
const button = document.getElementById('btn-id');
button.addEventListener('click', async _ => {
    try {
      console.log(document.querySelector('.area-id'))
      const response = await fetch('/', {
        method: 'post',
        body: document.querySelector('.area-id').innerText,
      });
      console.log('Completed!', response);
    } catch(err) {
      console.error(`ERRORE!`);
      console.error(`Error: ${err}`);
    }
});
```

However when I try to print the text of the textarea it comes out as an empty string... could someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to obtain the text added to a textarea is to use the `.value` property, not the `.innerText`

So simply change to

```
body: document.querySelector('.area-id').value
```

And your fetch request should be correct. I am assuming of course that you have the correct class "area-id" in your textarea